# useEffect on child component fires every other click

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I have a "Zones" component that has a "heatmapConfig" useState. This state is passed via props to a HeatmapConfiguration component, inside which I want to have a useEffect hook that detects when an option changes (the option is basically a checkbox to turn an option on and off).
The parent component is:

```
export const Zones = () => {
    const [heatmapConfig, setHeatmapConfig] = useState({active: false});
    return (
            <HeatmapConfiguration 
                state={heatmapConfig} setState=setHeatmapConfig} />
            <Map>
            {heatmapConfig.active && <HeatmapLeaflet {...{ mapRef, heatmapData, heatmapConfig }} />}
            </Map>
    )
}
```

Then the child is passed through the  component and it's as follows:

```
export const HeatmapLeaflet = ({ mapRef, heatmapData, heatmapConfig }) => {
    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(heatmapConfig);
    },[heatmapConfig]);
}
```

When I click to turn on the option it logs {active: true}, but nothing is logged when I turn it off.
If I place the useEffect hook in the parent component, it obviously works as intended, logging each time the option is on and off, I just don't know how to make it work on the child component. Having the useEffect in the parent won't be good in case you suggest that change, since with that tons of other stuff must change.

The Map component is a leaflet map container and I think the only part relevant to this case is:

```
export const Map = ({ children }) => {
    return(
        {children}
    )
}
```

EDIT:
Within the  component I have two others which are working as expected (PerHourScatter and StopsScatter):

```
<Map>
{scatterplotConfig.active && <PerHourScatter {...{ scatterplotData, scatterplotConfig }} />}
{stopsScatterConfig.active && <StopsScatter {...{ stopsScatterData, stopsScatterConfig }} />}
{heatmapConfig.active && <HeatmapLeaflet {...{ mapRef, heatmapData, heatmapConfig }} />}
</Map>
```

**By the comments I realize the difference is that the HeatmapLeaflet component doesn't actually render, it returns emtpy like this: return <></>;
I may have to follow a different approach, and maybe create this component not as a component but as a custom hook?**

How do I solve this?

Comment: HeatmapConfiguration, HeatmapLeaflet 

What do you mean HeatmapLeaflet is a child, I see no such thing.

Comment: You are right, it's not exactly a direct children, it's passed through another component called <Map /> @NicolaiChristensen

Comment: Why don't you use useContext to set the state in the parent and access the data in the child?

Comment: Maybe this is because you only render the leaflet when `heatmapConfig.active` is true: `heatmapConfig.active && <HeatmapLeaflet...`. When you turn it off, the `.active` returns False, thus not rendering the `HeatmapLeaflet`, thus not running the effect

Comment: @BaoHuynhLam this is a good idea, but it's not the case, since I have two other components that follow exactly the same pattern.

Comment: You know @BaoHuynhLam your comment made me realize, the HeatmapLeaflet component does not actually render anything, it has a useEffect that draws the heatmap, and then it simply returns this:  return <></>; 
I feel we are getting closer...